# Is there any way to run a selfsigned java applet without lowering java security policy?

Tags: java, security, applet

I am working on a small java applet tool, among other things to load some images from the hard disk, and upload them to the host server.
The problem is that I don't want a verified CA to sign it, and I need the Java security settings still on "high" in the Java control panel.
The applet should run on few computers, and is not publicly available.

Now when I load the HTML page, with the security settings on "high" (default/recommended), the JRE blocks this applet because it is not CA signed. Security set to "medium" works fine, but the security settings should not be lowered only for this tool.

Is there any way to sort of add this applet as a "trusted applet", allowing it to read files and connect it to the host server through a socket connection?

Thanks

Comment: A quick google picks up a one year code signing certificate below $100. Almost certainly it's not economical to do something dodgy. / You presumably don't want to give the applet elevated permissions when you sign it. There's documentation on the Oracle web sites.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding yourself as a root CA on the browsers concerned.

Comment: I think that's considered dangerous.

Comment: Not sure why.  You're asking those users to trust that apps you sign are safe to run.  Only dangerous if you betray their trust by losing/handing out your private key.  Same as any root CA.  (More generally, he would be asking his users to trust HIM, or the person in his role.  The key has to be managed properly, including invalidating it when he loses it or leaves the org.)